# [Node.js]How to access files in different directory using readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js

Under directory main:

- css(foler)

  - stylesheet.css
- js(folder)

  - data.js
  - server.js
- index.html

And inside server.js:

```
    //Cannot access index.html
    file.readFile('index.html', 'utf8', function(err, contents){
      //some code
    });
```

Specifically, how do we access **stylesheet.css** and **index.html**

Comment: Could you please add little bit more details. What is the [current directory](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processcwd) for the node process and does it contain the 'index.html' file.

Answer (score 1):

when you start the server, a global variable called `__dirname` is set that holds the absolute path of the folder that `server.js` is inside. Now we can use that value to read files relative to `server.js` file. In the following code, I used `path.join()` to construct the path to the files that you want to access. The double dots (`..`) is the directory above the js folder.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Get the absulote path of the files
const htmlFile = path.join(__dirname, "..", "index.html");
const cssFile = path.join(__dirname, "..", "css", "stylesheet.css");

// Read files
fs.readFile(htmlFile, "utf8", function (err, content) {
  console.log(content);
});

fs.readFile(cssFile, "utf8", function (err, content) {
  console.log(content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing folders on a top level directory you can use `..` in your path.

Access `index.html` in `server.js`

```js
//access top level directory using `..`
file.readFile('../index.html', 'utf8', function(err, contents){
  //some code
});

file.readFile('../css/stylesheet.css', 'utf8', function(err, contents){
  //some code
});
```

Ideally you would always import from absolute paths. That prevents breaking your app when you restructure it. I suggest to always start your app from the root directory of your project like `node js/server.js` .

When starting it from root the `process.cwd()` (current working directory.) variable will always point to the root dir of the project and file reads could be done using:

```js
var { join } = require('path')
var htmlFile = join(process.cwd(), 'index.html')
var cssFile = join(process.cwd(), 'css', 'stylesheet.css')

// read html file
file.readFile(htmlFile, 'utf8', function(err, contents){
  //some code
});

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add ".", so it will be :

```
fs.readFile("./../index.html", "utf8", (err, content){ return })
```